# change background <tr> if date expired using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table with many dates

example:

```
<table>

<tr>
<td>23/12/2018</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>21/12/2018</td>
</tr>


</table>
```

Now if td value = Same day and before (Depending on the date of the day) I want to color `<tr>` background to red

example: if value = 21/12/2018, tr background = red.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach would be to iterate through each table `td` via `document.querySelectorAll()` like so:

```
document.querySelectorAll('table td').forEach(function(td) {
    ...
})
```

where for each `td` that is iterated, extract the `innerText` of that td, parse it to a `Date()` object:

```
 var dateParts = str.split('/');
 var date = new Date();

 date.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
 date.setDate(dateParts[0]);
 date.setMonth(dateParts[1]);
 date.setFullYear(dateParts[2]);
```

And then apply a background style of `red` to the current `td` if the parsed date comes before the current date:

```js
function getDateFromString(str) {

  var dateParts = str.split('/');
  var date = new Date();
  
  date.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
  date.setDate(dateParts[0]);
  date.setMonth(dateParts[1] - 1);
  date.setFullYear(dateParts[2]);
  
  return date;
}

// Query all table cells in document
document.querySelectorAll('table td').forEach(function(td) {
  
  // If date contained in td text before current date 
  // then apply red background style
  
  var today = new Date();
  today.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
  
  if( getDateFromString(td.innerText) <= today ) {
    
    td.style.background = 'red';
  }  
});
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>25/12/2018</td>
  </tr>      
  <tr>
    <td>23/12/2018</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>21/12/2018</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I want to be relying on today's real date and not just 21/12/2018

Comment: @AhmadAkal just updated code snippet - does this work for you?

Comment: @AhmadAkal oh ok - just updated code snippet , does that match your requirements now?

Comment: I'm sorry I made a mistake in the question
I want to be today and before it is red

Comment: @AhmadAkal no problems - just updated answer. Does that work for you now?

Comment: Great! Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

Using jquery you can loop through each `td` element using `.each()` and then you can compare today's date and the `td`'s date using `.setHours` on both date objects.

See working example below (read code comments for further explanation):

```js
const today = new Date(); // Get today's date
$('table tr td').each(function() {
  let dateData = $(this).text().split('/'); // get the components of today's date
  let tdDate = new Date(+dateData[2], dateData[1] - 1, +dateData[0]); // reate a date object from your string in the td element

  if(tdDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0) == today.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)) { // compare the two dates
    $(this).css({"background": "red"}); // change the color of the element if it matches
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>

  <tr>
    <td>23/12/2018</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>21/12/2018</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over the `td` columns and check the dates with the corresponding attributes from the javascript `Date` object:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var _date = new Date();
  $('td').each(function(){
    var d = $(this).text().split('/');
    if (parseInt(d[0]) === _date.getDate() && parseInt(d[1]) === _date.getMonth()+1 && parseInt(d[2]) === _date.getFullYear()){
      $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: @AhmadAkal This is the code that is simply placed in between the `<script></script>` tags. Can you clarify?